# Windows VM, avoiding CPU switches for long-running processes

Tags: windows, virtual-machine

Looking at the load graph of the CPUs on my build machine, it seems that Windows is repeatedly rescheduling the compiler to run on a different CPU core.

That would make sense on a physical machine for thermal management, however this is a VM inside an overcommitted host, which then scrambles to schedule the virtual CPUs that are currently running onto different physical CPUs.

Is there a way to tell Windows to stop rescheduling long-running processes all the time, and/or am I severely overestimating the impact this has on performance?

Comment: Commonly it is overestimated, it is said don't optimized until you are sure it is the problem. BTW a building process will constantly fork new compiler processes, each only live for seconds - are you sure it is a long running process?

Comment: CPU-bound processes on an overcommited host are a PITA independent of the guest scheduling strategy: The assumption, that a single vCPU is available for a continuous stretch of time breaks.

Comment: @jw_, this is Visual Studio, which uses a single `cl.exe` invocation for all sources in the same project that have the same options.

Comment: When I use Visual Studio to build there are many cl.exe consume all the CPU time.

Comment: @EugenRieck, that assumption holds most of the time (that's why the host is overcommitted -- it'd be a waste of CPUs otherwise), and the host scheduler usually does a good job if a few vCPUs are pegged out, but not so many that we run out of physical CPUs -- then the vCPUs get a fixed mapping to physical CPUs, and interrupts are kept off those physical CPUs as well, which would be ideal conditions for caching as well.

Comment: @jw_, do you use the `/MP` option, perhaps? You can tell VS to spawn more parallel processes, but [not accidentally starting more compilers than you have CPUs is hard](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/436208/limit-cpu-usage-of-visual-studio.html).

Comment: Now I check the pid of cl.exe, they are indeed the same... gcc/clang can't do this right - they are one process per invocation?

Comment: @jw_, gcc uses several subprocesses per source file, with the compiler generating assembler text, and a separate assembler process generating the binary, so these cannot be sensibly merged.

Comment: @SimonRichter I guess merging like cl.exe does doesn't have real benefit, on contrast it make compiler development harder.